# How to execute or run FGLTTY command line in Java without GUI?

Tags: java, eclipse, performance, network-protocols, genero

Is there a way to run the command line below within a Java application without opening FGLTTY GUI?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(   
     "cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"C:\\Users\\test\\exe\" && fgltty -u sq5");

    builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process p = builder.start();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = r.readLine();
        if (line == null) { break; }
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

If I run the above Java code, it establishes a connection via FGLTTY with server IP `10.171.0.105` and prompts to give `/usr/bin/test.sh`. 
Instead, I want to open it without GUI.